# How do I encode/decode a string properly with .decode("utf-8")?

Tags: python, basehttprequesthandler

I am trying to pass a dict variable to a remote server using BaseHTTPRequestHandler, but using `json.dumps()`, my server sees:

```
%7B%22ID%22%3A+%7B%22type%22%3A+%22title%22%2C+%22search%22%3A+%22test%22%7D%7D
```

instead of:

```
{id: {'type': 'title', 'search': 'test'}}
```

I have tried using `data.decode("utf-8")`, but that is just giving me an error as the data is already a string. I know I'm probably encoding/decoding wrong, but is there any way of getting from what it is already returning into the json format?

Comment: You need to url decode it.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Normally this would be handled by whatever code is interacting with the http protocol.  You're likely fetching it from the wrong place (and hence bypassing the relevant decoding) or whatever is sending it is "double encoding" the data, which would be good to fix if that's possible

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`unquote_plus`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote_plus) function from `urllib.parse` module:

```py
import json
import urllib.parse

text = '%7B%22ID%22%3A+%7B%22type%22%3A+%22title%22%2C+%22search%22%3A+%22test%22%7D%7D'
json_text = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(text)
json_data = json.loads(json_text)
print(json_data)
```

It outputs

```
{'ID': {'type': 'title', 'search': 'test'}}
```